# Unknown magic byte when using Confluent S3 Sink connector and JsonSchemaConverter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I have a MSK topic, where I will receive plain JSON data. All the data will follow the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$id": "events-schema",
  "title": "Events schema",
  "description": "Schema of messages in the the events topic",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "timestamp": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "source": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "payload": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "timestamp",
    "source",
    "payload"
  ]
}
```

So they will differ in the "payload", where some will have more or less fields.

I need to write it to S3 in Parquet format, but as specified in the documentation, https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html#s3-object-formats I must use AvroConverter, ProtobufConverter or JsonSchemaConverter, with an schema.

So I created an EC2 instance with the Confluent Registry in the same VPC as the MSK cluster, and as test I added the sample schema from https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#example-requests-format-and-valid-json

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/subjects/test/versions -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json' -d '{"schema":"{\"type\": \"record\",\"name\": \"test\",\"fields\":[{\"type\": \"string\",\"name\": \"field1\"},{\"type\": \"int\",\"name\": \"field2\"}]}"}'
```

And sent a simple message using the kafka-console-producer sh:

```
{"field1":"test4578_01","field2":1}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
2023-10-26T10:50:10.000+02:00   [Worker-0274eded1d816e946] Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1

2023-10-26T10:50:10.000+02:00   [Worker-0274eded1d816e946] Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
```

My connector is using the following properties:

```
    "key.converter" = "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    "value.converter"                     = "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
    "value.converter.schemas.enable"      = false
    "value.converter.avroRecordType"      = "GENERIC_RECORD"
    "value.converter.dataFormat"          = "JSON"
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url" = "http://<ec2 instance IP>:8081"

    "connector.class" = "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector"
```

Is there any parameter I am missing? How can I deserialize the data?